# How to load a PLY mesh with triangles and (isolated) vertices in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to display an object that contains triangles and isolated vertices in Three.js. It's encoded in a PLY. I use THREE.Mesh for showing the triangles, and THREE.Points for the points, feeding the same `geometry` object to both. However, only the vertices belonging to triangles are displayed.

I also did a test where I conserved the vertices but removed all the triangles (faces) in the PLY file. In that case, all vertices are displayed...

What can I do to have both?

I'm including a small test PLY file, which has 4 vertices, 3 of them belonging to a triangle. If you load it with this code, you'll see that only the 3 vertices in the triangle are displayed.

```js
const meshString = `ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 4
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 1
property list uchar int vertex_indices
element edge 0
property int vertex1
property int vertex2
end_header
-1 1 0.000000 
1 1 0.000000 
1 -1 0.000000 
-1 -1 0.000000 
3 0 1 3
`;
const loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
geometry = loader.parse( meshString );
const meshPoints = new THREE.Points( geometry, pointsMaterial );
scene.add(meshPoints);
```

#### Edit 1

Here's a picture showing what I would like to get, and what I actually get:
[image: a, b: wish, c: sad reality]

#### Edit 2

I made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/r03ert0/pen/GREprKM) showing the problem.

#### Edit 3

I found the problem, but I'd still be very interested in knowing if there's a good solution. What happens is that PLYLoader creates an index if there are faces, and the index only contains vertices belonging to faces. If there's no faces, index=null, and we get all the vertices. Creating a version of the geometry without index using `geometry.toNonIndexed` doesn't help, because only vertices belonging to faces are conserved. One solution is to manually set `geometry.index=null`, in which case the missing vertices are rendered.

Comment: "_isolated vertices_" what do you mean with this?

Comment: vertices which do not belong to any triangle. It's the case of vertex 2 in the test file (the triangle only contains vertices 0, 1 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a clone of the geometry and set `geometry.index=null` as in Edit #3. However, this will make a copy of the vertices. To prevent that, do like this:

```js
const loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
const geometry = loader.parse(meshString);

// the mesh: for displaying the triangles
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Mesh.meshMaterial);
scene.add(mesh);

// the points: even those outside triangles
const geometry2 = geometry.clone(); // clone the original geometry
geometry2.index = null; // do not use indexing
geometry2.attributes.position = geometry.attributes.position; // use the same vertices as the original mesh
meshPoints = new THREE.Points( geometry2, Mesh.pointsMaterial );
scene.add(meshPoints);
```